# last date of previous month returning 30 days for May

Tags: java, date

I am using the below code to retrieve the last day in the previous month - Ex: May. But it is returning 30 days instead of 31.

The code given below

```
package net.vcmg.date;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public class LastDayPreviousMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = addMonths(lastDayOfTheMonth(today()), -1);
        System.out.println("lastDateOfPreviousMonth: "+lastDateOfPreviousMonth);

    }

    //the below method is from Utils.java
    public static Date lastDayOfTheMonth(Date d) {
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
           cal.setTime(d);
           int actualMax = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
           cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, actualMax);
           return cal.getTime();
    }

    public static Date addMonths(Date date, int numMonths)
    {
        return DateUtils.addMonths(date, numMonths);
    }

    public static Date today()
    {
        return truncDate(now());
    }

    public static Date now()
    {
        // will cut-off milliseconds
        return new Date( (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) * 1000);
    }

    public static Date truncDate (Date date) {
        return DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DATE);
    }

}
```

Here, when i call the lastDateOfPreviousMonth in the main method, it is returning 30 days alone. Not the 31 , May contains 31 days actually. Please help.

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = lastDayOfTheMonth(addMonths(today(), -1));
        System.out.println("lastDateOfPreviousMonth: " + lastDateOfPreviousMonth);

    }
```

When you call lastDayOfTheMonth for today() day will be 30. And after minus one month result expected will be 30, not 31.

Answer (score 6):

**Java 8**

If you are not constraint to use the old `Date` it will be better to use the new `java.time.LocalDate`

```
LocalDate previousMonth = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);

LocalDate start = previousMonth.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate end = previousMonth.withDayOfMonth(previousMonth.lengthOfMonth());
System.out.println(start);
System.out.println(end);
```

Output

```
2019-05-01
2019-05-31
```

**Edit**

For your implementation, change the order of methods

1. addMonths - get the current date and provide the previous month `addMonths(new Date(), -1)`
2. lastDayOfTheMonth - get the last day of the previous month `lastDayOfTheMonth(addMonths(new Date(), -1))`

```
Date lastDateOfPreviousMonth = lastDayOfTheMonth(addMonths(new Date(), -1));
```

Output

```
lastDateOfPreviousMonth: Fri May 31 10:46:13 EEST 2019
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s a logical error in the way you have thought out your program/algorithm. You are first finding the last day of the month, in this case June 30. You are then subtracting 1 month. That gives May 30 regardless of the fact that there are 31 days in May (it’s not explicit from the documentation of `DateUtils.addMonths` that it works this way, but it uses the poorly designed and outdated `Calendar` class internally, so this is what we should expect).

Instead do things in the opposite order. First find the previous month:

```
YearMonth lastMonth = YearMonth.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")).minusMonths(1);
```

> 2019-05

Since the new month doesn’t begin at the same point in time in all time zones, I recommend that you state your desired time zone as shown.

Only then find the last day of the month:

```
LocalDate lastDayOfLastMonth = lastMonth.atEndOfMonth();
```

> 2019-05-31

### Avoid Date and Calendar

I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. This will also save you from the external dependency on Apache `DateUtils` since its functionality is generally built into the modern classes.

### Links

- [Documentation of `org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.addMonths`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#addMonths-java.util.Date-int-)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.